# git equivalent for hg rollback

Tags: git

How would I "rollback" the last commit in git without deleting any changes?

This is something I've done often in hg:

- Commit "Fixed 107."
- Remembered that I forgot to do *something*
- hg rollback
- Do *something*
- Commit "Fixed 107."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With git you may actually prefer to use the `--amend` option in that case.

- Commit "Fixed 107."
- Remembered that I forgot to do something
- Do something
- `git commit --amend` and edit the notes

If you need to rollback for other reasons take a look at `git revert`

Comment: `revert` is a way to deal with only one of several other reasons. If the commit in question as been published, then indeed, use `git revert`. If it hasn't been pushed, and it's the most recent commit, use `git reset [--hard] HEAD^`. If it hasn't been pushed, and it's not the most recent commit, use `git rebase -i` to remove it from the history, leaving the rest intact.

Comment: Beware git noobs (like me). I did "git reset HEAD^" and it not only removed my commit from history but also reverted the commited files to their previous commit state.

Comment: @DaviLima `git reset HEAD^` shouldn't do that, it should only modify the files in your working directory if you also use the `--hard` flag.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

I found it to be the same of 'hg rollback', because:

- last commit cancelled
- changes preserved
- files previously committed are staged

You can also create a `rollback` git alias like this:

```
git config --global alias.rollback 'reset --soft HEAD^'
```

So, you can now just type `git rollback` to have exactly the same command that you have on Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific instance I would `git commit --amend`.  If you haven't pushed yet and you've already committed other changes then you can also use `git rebase -i` to edit whichever commit you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do an hg rollback in my git repository and I managed using

```
git reset HEAD~
```

this left me with my changes in the working directory but now unstaged. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440050/how-to-split-last-commit-into-two-in-git)