# How split a huge code to small patches in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, git-review

Currently, I want to contribute to OpenStack and I am new to Gerrit.
In Gerrit, I created a new branch `my_branch` but actually my code is very huge. Please kindly let me know how I can split my code to smaller changes with the same branch `my_branch`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split last commit into two in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440050/how-to-split-last-commit-into-two-in-git)

Comment: It looks like different.. I'm sorry for making you confused. I changed my title. I means I just had a huge code in my local repository, no patch in Gerrit existed before. Now I want to split my code to several parts so that I can commit them with some corresponding changes. But I want the branch "my_branch" to be same with these changes. Is it clear to you?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the same. Has nothing to do with Gerrit, can all be done on the Git level.

Comment: Totally agree. But when I saw in the accepted answer, someone wants to split a file. My question is if I have several files .py like file1.py, file2.py,..., file5.py. Now I want to combine (file1.py & file2.py) in one change, (file3.py, file4.py and file5.py) in another change. Two changes are the sane branch. How can I do it?

Comment: It depends on your code and where you want to contribute it to (which repository exactly). This has nothing to do with gerrit, though, it's a general git question. Show us your code.

Comment: So have you commited anything? Did you make a single, big commit that you want to split, or do you have several commits that you want to rearrange?

Comment: @Dunno: Absolutely No. I just have some code. And now I have intention to separate them into several parts. And then i will commit these parts.

Answer (score -1):

Pleaas tray git gui tools - citool, gitk.

`git citool` gives possibility to choose which files and even which  lines you put in new commit.

Very useful maybe also `gitk` command which show your commits tree. `gitk` gives also posibility to run some other git comman from gui.